# Restarting my laptop (Dell XPS 9350) with external monitors connected causes black screen on laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, screen, restart

I have had this issue for a long time and would like some help on what could be the issue here.

I have a dell xps 9350 laptop with ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on it.

When i have my external monitors connected to it and and with lid closed and performs a restart of the computer the laptops screen is always black when i open the the lid and disconnects the external monitor which forces me to manually restart the laptop with the power button.

This is extremely frustrating since i am in and out of meetings and constantly have to do this.

Anyone out here have any issue if this is ubuntu related.. dell related ? And maybe a solution, Thanks.